# gitlab server-side project-specific custom hook not running

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to set up server-side project-specific custom hooks. I followed the instructions as listed here 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html

I made a custom_hooks directory inside the directory of my project Jenkins_test.git. Inside the custom_hooks directory is a pre-receive hook file named pre-receive

The permissions set for the custom_hooks directory are as follows
drwxrwx--x  2 git git 4096 Nov  9 19:25 custom_hooks

The permissions set for the pre-receive custom hook are as follows
-rwxrwxr-x 1 git git  48 Nov  7 14:06 pre-receive

The content of the pre-receive hook file is as follows
#!/bin/bash
echo "HELLO THIS IS A CUSTOM HOOK"

When executed directly from the command line the pre-receive file executes without any problems.

The expectation is for the pre-receive hook to be executed everytime someone pushes something to the Jenkins_test project. It should run before the push is accepted because the actual use is to check certain parameters that will decide whether to accept or reject the incoming push. But the problem is that it never gets executed.